# VBScript could not locate WindowSystemObject class, error code 80020009 (Windows 10, 20H2)

Tags: forms, vbscript

When I'm trying to create a simple form:
`Set WSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.WindowSystemObject")`
I am getting this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjAoi.png
Is this feature some kind of obsolete? I checked it on 2 machines with the same result.
Both running Windows 10, 20H2. How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is WSO installed?

Comment: Ooooh... I am an idiot:) I thought it was a built-in functionality, not a downloadable tool. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe WindowSystemObject (WSO) needs to be installed for this to work.

I found a download link here.

[WindowSystemObject](http://veretennikov.org/Default.aspx?f=WSO%2FDefault.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, thank you too. I am so absentminded. Although mr. Rno already answered this, he did it in comment, and unfortunately I see no option to accept his answer (new to this site), so I will accept yours.